# How to fit a DIV all page?

Tags: html, expand

I'm a beginner so I don't understand much about HTML and CSS.

My problem is:

I created a DIV and i want that div expands to all page with 100% width and 100% height but currently i can't do that.

Someone can help me?

(Sorry for bad english)

Regards.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window

Answer (score 0):

for 
jquery:

```
$('div').css('position', 'fixed');
$('div').css('width', $('body').css('width'));
$('div').css('height', $('body').css('height'));
```

js:

```
document.getElementById('divId').style["position"] = 'fixed';
document.getElementById('divId').style["width"] = document.body.offsetWidth;
document.getElementById('divId').style["height"] = document.body.offsetHeight;
```

css:

```
#yourDivId {width:1000px; height:1000px; position: fixed;}
```

Comment: NONONO! why not width:100%; height:100%?